# How do I install Windows 7 onto the HDD while on Kali live usb?

Tags: windows-7, boot, kali-linux, reinstall, livecd

I have a problem installing Windows 7 after I messed up files on drive C.

Now I have two folders named windows.old and windows.old000

After more than one failed attempt to complete the Windows 7 installation process. Now I can't install Windows 7 anymore from the flash drive that I normally use to reinstall Windows 7.

Every time I try to boot from a Windows 7 bootable usb, the computer always boots from the HDD even though I have set up the first boot from the usb drive.

After I thought the USB drive was in trouble then I bought a new 16 GB flash drive and filled it with Windows 7 ISO from Kali Live USB using WoeUSB.  But it's still the same, I can't boot from the new flash drive, but the computer always boots from the HDD that can't startup (I can't even start because the Windows installation process has failed twice).

I can still access the Windows files on the HDD from Kali Linux Live USB, and I think there is a possibility I can install Windows 7 from Kali  Live USB.

Is that possible?

If so, how can I do that?

Additional information: after several attempts I was happy to be able to boot from a flash drive, but it didn't last long because for some reason the windows installation process still couldn't be finished. The first time it stopped at 87%, and the last stop at 44%. I think something is wrong with the HDD or something.

Comment: Brand of PC? Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: It is Asus notebook.